# Trying to access array elements: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to write a function that adds up the elements in an array. Unfortunately, every time I try to access the array elements, I get the abovementioned error message when I compile. What is going on?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int arraySum(ar, number) {
    int x = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        x += ar[i];
    }
    return x;
}


int main (void) {
    int ar[4] = {3,6,9,12};
    int number = 4;

    printf("The sum is %i",arraySum(ar[4], number));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int arraySum(ar, number) {` --> `int arraySum(int ar[], int number) {`, `arraySum(ar[4], number)` --> `arraySum(ar, number)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your code should look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int arraySum(int ar[], int number) {
    int x = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        x += ar[i];
    }
    return x;
}


int main (void) {
    int ar[4] = {3,6,9,12};
    int number = 4;

    printf("The sum is %i",arraySum(ar, number));

    return 0;
}
```

You can test it here
http://codepad.org/a2dZzzsG

You completely forgot to declare the types of the arraySum() parameters, so compiler did not know what to expect at first, and then you also tried to pass ar[4] to the function, which is not a valid index vor the a array and would, even if you had 5 members, just pass one int value and not the whole array.

Answer (score 1):

1) `int arraySum(ar, number)` - in function declaration you have to provide type for parameters. But you don't.
2) In `main` you are trying to access `ar[4]`, which is fifth element of `ar`, which has only 4 elements.

Comment: I like this because it leaves the work of correcting the errors to OP, meaning the learning experience will be more valuable and memorable for OP.